# how to mark unread email in outlook to read using visual studio 2013

Tags: outlook, vb.net-2010

Hello I'developing the outlook addin which will automate the task of extracting unread emails with no attachment in a folder & extracting attachments to the folder.However I'm able to code the extracting of attachments from emails to folder but I realized two issues that I should have pointed out. Some emails may contain more than 1 attachment and some attachments may have the same filename (and need to be auto renamed when extracted to prevent overwriting).so I'm not able to understand how to code it?Also I want code for the emails with no attachments retrieved in a specific folder.Please help with this. Below is the code which extract attachment in a folder from emails.
Public Class ThisAddIn

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    Dim inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder = Me.Application.ActiveExplorer.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
    Dim unreadItems As Outlook.Items = inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true")
    Dim inboxItems As Outlook.Items = inbox.Items.Restrict("[Unread]=true")
    Dim newEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    MsgBox(String.Format("Unread items in Inbox = {0}", unreadItems.Count))
    Try
        For Each collectionItem As Object In inboxItems
            newEmail = TryCast(collectionItem, Outlook.MailItem)
            If newEmail IsNot Nothing Then
                If newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                    For i As Integer = 1 To newEmail.Attachments.Count
                        For j As Integer = i + 1 To newEmail.Attachments.Count
                            ' Dim saveAttachment As Outlook.Attachments = newEmail.Attachments(i)
                            If newEmail.Attachments(i).FileName.Equals(newEmail.Attachments(j).FileName) Then
                                newEmail.Attachments(j).SaveAsFile("C:\Attachment\Copy\" & (newEmail.Attachments(j).FileName))

                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next (j)
                        newEmail.Attachments(i).SaveAsFile("C:\Attachment\" & (newEmail.Attachments(i).FileName))
                    Next (i)
                End If

            End If

        Next collectionItem

    Catch ex As Exception
        If Left(ex.Message, 11) = "Cannot Save" Then
            MsgBox("Create Folder C:\Attachment")
        End If

    End Try



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd certainly have to use your own logic to come up with a unique file name in conjunction with using System.IO.File.Exists.  A simple loop and appending a number to the name should suffice for file name collisions.

But what exactly do you mean by "I want code for the emails with no attachments retrieved in a specific folder".  Do you want to hook into the Folder.Items.ItemAdd event for a specific folder to detect when new emails are delivered or added to that folder?  Or do you want to move emails with no attachments to a specific folder?